# Product of Mittag-Leffler functions $E_\alpha(x) \cdot E_\alpha(y)$

Tags: exponential-function, fractional-calculus

For the exponential function, the following relation holds:
\begin{equation}
e^x\cdot e^y = e^{x+y}
\end{equation}

The Mittag-Leffler function 
\begin{equation}
E_\alpha(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}
\end{equation}

is a kind of "generalization" of the exponential function.

My question: is there a similar relation for the product of two Mittag-Leffler functions like:

\begin{equation}
E_\alpha(x) \cdot E_\alpha(y)
\end{equation}

or, in particular, even

\begin{equation}
E_\alpha(x) \cdot E_\alpha(y) \stackrel{?}{=} E_\alpha(x+y)
\end{equation}

Comment: Is True, only for: $\alpha =1$.

Comment: But is there a known expression for $E_\alpha(x) \cdot E_\alpha(y)$ (apparently different to $E_\alpha(x+y)$) ?

Comment: I don't know....